# How can I access the next row in pandas dataframe after a certain cell value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe (11520 rows × 12 columns). I want to get all rows where there is a certain value in column 11 in the row before.

Example:

```
   age sex  correct    D
0   20   f        0  345
1   21   m        1  744
2   22   f        0  234
3   23   m        0  247
4   24   f        1  845
```

If I want to get all rows with a `0` in column `correct` in the previous row my result should be:

```
   age sex  correct    D
1   21   m        1  744
3   23   m        0  247
4   24   f        1  845
```

How can I access these rows?

Comment: in output there are 2 values equal 23 in `age` column, but only 1 such row in input dataframe, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `shift()` here:

```py
>>> df.loc[df["correct"].shift().eq(0)]

   age sex  correct    D
1   21   m        1  744
3   23   m        0  247
4   24   f        1  845
```

Ref. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html

Answer (score 2):

Given `df`:

```
   age sex  correct    D
0   20   f        0  345
1   21   m        1  744
2   22   f        0  234
3   23   m        0  247
4   24   f        1  845
```

`df[df.correct.shift(1).eq(0)]`

result:

```
   age sex  correct    D
1   21   m        1  744
3   23   m        0  247
4   24   f        1  845
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Series.shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) method. Here, we create a new column by shifting the 'correct' column by 1 row and then subset using the new column.

```
df['correct_prev'] = df['correct'].shift(1)
df.loc[df.correct_prev == 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the point. The following code would do the trick.

```
import pandas as pd 

data = {'age':[20,21,22,23,24],'sex':['f','m','f','m','f'],
       'correct':[0,1,0,0,1],'D':[345,744,234,247,845]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def func(c_name,val):
    index = [] 
    for i in range(len(df)):
        if df[c_name].iloc[i] ==  val:
            index.append(i+1)
    return index

lst = func(c_name='correct',val=0)

df.iloc[lst]
```